# Не могу разобраться с таблицами HTML

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**Должно получится так, как на фото, однако rowspan не работает**

```html
<table border=2>
  <tr>
    <td align=center width=50 rowspan=2>1,6</td>
    <td align=center width=50>2</td>
    <td align=center width=50 rowspan=2>3,8</td>
    <td align=center width=50>4</td>
    <td align=center width=50 rowspan=2>5,10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center width=50 rowspan=2>7,12</td>
    <td align=center width=50 rowspan=2>9,14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center width=50>11</td>
    <td align=center width=50>13</td>
    <td align=center width=50>15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Добавьте в первую колонку атрибут `height=50` и будет красиво смотреться. А лучше это все сделать стилями css